# Where's sample data of Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm reading the doc of SQL Server at MS website such as

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Where can I find the sample data used here?

Comment: you need to download the AdventureWorks  database from the Microsoft website

Comment: You can download Adventureworks from codeplex: https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AdventureWorks is a sample database provided by SQL Server. This can be downloaded from the below location,

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/